# Website slows down every time cronjob is executed

Tags: php, asynchronous, curl, cron, litespeed

I have a cronjob A that works every minute. This actually executes a PHP file B via curl, which should be executed every 5 seconds. (I know 5 seconds is insane, but we need it to keep what we're doing in real-time)

PHP file B has the following code at the beginning of the file to make the operation asynchronous.

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_start();
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 202 Accepted");
header("Status: 202 Accepted");
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
```

The time it takes B to execute is about 1 second when the process is asynchronous and about 4 seconds when it's synchronous. Since it's a cronjob and we don't need to give data back to our user instantly, async is the best option we can use.

So cronjob A runs every minute and calls PHP file B 12 times each time so that the file will be executed every 5 seconds. This whole process takes about 12 seconds. I would love to do this directly with a cronjob, but the lowest option is every single minute.

The problem is that the website lags for a while when the cronjob is executed. We were using a virtual machine with 32 vCPUs on Provider A, but as of today we have switched to 64 vCPUs on Provider B. I think our resources are not insufficient to cover this single cronjob and there was also no problem previously. But somehow, it lags the website now. I don't know what to do or what settings to change.

Looking forward to your valuable answers.

I tried to delete this particular cronjob and everything seems to be fine without it. So I'm pretty sure it was that cronjob that was delaying the website.

I tried to increase the "Number of Workers" in Litespeed from "Not set" to "16". But it didn't affect anything.

Comment: You need to figure out *why* it lags. What does the job do? What happens when it takes more than five seconds? What's the bottleneck? Does it make database queries, HTTP requests, or something that might take a while?

Comment: (1) Do you have an option to increase the amount of RAM in the server ? (2) Can you get another server to handle the cronjob ?

Comment: @ceejayoz the PHP file B executes a CLI command which can take a while. But it is not because of our system. Then with the result of that CLI command we update our database. But most of the time goes for it to execute the CLI command. Around 3.5 to execute and 0.5 to update the database.

Comment: @KenLee the server has 256GB memory and we don't even use %1 of it when the cronjob is executed. I don't think it is the main problem and unfortunately we cannot get another server to handle just one cronjob. But thank you for the answer.